# Accuracy of the radiocarbon method (from a mathematical point of view)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, physics

Consider the following situation: We have an ice core and we know that the age distribution of air bubbles entrapped at depth $d$ is $p(a,d)$ with $\int_{0}^\infty p(a,d)\ \text{d}a = 1$ for all $d$. The distribution may be arbitrary, i.e. doesn't have to be normal.

We then have:

- The mean age of air bubbles at depth $d$ is

$$\overline{A}(d) = \int_{0}^\infty a\ p(a,d)\ \text{d}a$$

- The concentration of carbon $^{12}C$ at depth $d$ is

$$\overline{^{12}C}(d) = \int_{0}^\infty\ ^{12}C(-a) \ p(a,d) \ \text{d}a$$

where $^{12}C(t)=\,^{12}C(-a)$ is the concentration of $^{12}C$ in the atmosphere at time $t\leq 0$ with $t=0$ meaning "today".

- The concentration of $^{14}C$ at depth $d$ is

$$\overline{^{14}C}(d) = \int_{0}^\infty\ ^{14}C(-a) e^{-\lambda\ a} \ p(a,d) \ \text{d}a = \alpha \int_{0}^\infty\ ^{12}C(-a)\ e^{- \lambda\ a } \ p(a,d) \ \text{d}a$$

with  $\alpha$ the ratio of $^{14}C/^{12}C$ in the atmosphere (which is assumed to be constant) and $\lambda$ the reciprocal of mean-life of $^{14}C$.

Applying the [radiocarbon method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating#Principles) means to calculate an age $\overline{^{14}A}(d)$ from the concentrations $\overline{^{14}C}(d)$ and $\overline{^{12}C}(d)$. This means to calculate

$$\overline{^{14}A}(d) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\ln\Big(\frac{\alpha\ \overline{^{12}C}(d)}{\overline{^{14}C}(d)}\Big)$$

Intuition tells that the age $\overline{^{14}A}(d)$ determined by the radiocarbon method must be approximately the mean age $\overline{A}(d)$ of air bubbles at depth $d$. But how to show this mathematically, and how to estimate the difference $\epsilon$ between the two depending on the shapes of $^{12}C(t)$ and $p(a,d)$ and on depth $d$?

So I want to show that

$$\overline{^{14}A}(d) = \overline{A}(d) + \epsilon(d)$$

with some (hopefully) small $\epsilon(d)$ or, respectively, find the $\epsilon(d)$ with

> $$\frac{1}{\lambda}\Bigg(\ln\alpha + \ln\Big(\int_{0}^\infty f(a) \
>  p(a,d)  \ \text{d}a\Big) - \ln\Big(\int_{0}^\infty f(a) \ p(a,d) \
>  e^{-\lambda\ a}\ \text{d}a\Big)\Bigg)\\ = \int_{0}^\infty a\
>  p(a,d)\ \text{d}a + \epsilon(d)$$

for good-natured functions $^{12}C(t)$ and $p(a,d)$. Let be $f(a) = ^{12}\kern-0.24emC(-a)$.

If I already made mistakes in the derivation of the problem, please excuse me and drop me a note. Otherwise I am keen to get a solution. How can – for example – it be shown that the difference $\epsilon$ is small when $p(a,d)$ is a narrow distribution around a mean, and that it is even smaller when it is a symmetric or even normal distribution?

---

**Addendum:**

The question is simpler when we consider the specific function $^{12}C(t) = k\ t$. Then we have

$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\Bigg(\ln\alpha + \ln\Big(\int_{0}^\infty a \
 p(a,d)  \ \text{d}a\Big) - \ln\Big(\int_{0}^\infty a \ p(a,d) \
 e^{-\lambda\ a}\ \text{d}a\Big)\Bigg)\\ = \int_{0}^\infty a\
 p(a,d)\ \text{d}a + \epsilon(d)$$

Can $\epsilon(d)$ be given exactly?

The error $\epsilon(d)$ can in fact be given exactly when $p(a,d)$ is a delta function, i.e. $p(a,d) = \delta(d - a\rho)$. Then we have

$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\Big(\ln\alpha + \ln f(d/\rho) - \ln\big(f(d/\rho)\ e^{-\lambda\ d/\rho}\big)\Big) = \ln\alpha/\lambda + d/\rho \\= d/\rho + \epsilon(d),$$

that means $\epsilon(d) = \epsilon = \ln\alpha / \lambda$. For small $\alpha$ and large $\lambda$ (as in the case of $^{14}C$), this error may be neglected. But I am interested in the general case.

Comment: I find it puzzling that $^xC$ are functions of both depth and time, but with only one argument. Is this notation correct?

Comment: Not quite correct. I hoped it would be clear from the context (and variable name) which function is intended. Should I make it perfectly clear and unambiguous?

Comment: You mean when $^xC$ is a function of time the argument is negative, right?

Comment: Right! Time is negative, age is positive.

Comment: We might be led to think we are dealing with an integral equation. I would put an index to differentiate tfrom he concentration in the air.

Comment: I'll do, but only tomorrow, sorry.

Comment: @minmax: I added an index in form of an overline. I hope everything is clear now. Do you have an answer (or a hint how to solve the problem)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here. The first is that the carbon method gives a certain sort of average with density $\asymp C(-a)p(a)$ (I omit $d$ because it is the same everywhere), not $p(a)$, so even if the logarithm of the ratio were a perfect mean age estimator, it would not give the mean for the true distribution, but the mean for the weighted distribution. The second issue is the logarithm and integrals itself. Your only real hope is that $p$ is essentially concentrated on an interval over which neither $C$, not $e^{-\lambda t}$ vary noticeably. Then you are in good shape.

Let's say that $p$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$ (I leave the scaling to you), $\log C$ is $\mu$-Lipshitz with small $\mu$ and $\lambda$ is also small. Then the worst case scenarios are when you take the extreme cases $C(a)=e^{\pm\mu a}$ resulting in the deviations between $\frac\lambda 2-\mu$ and $\frac \lambda 2+\mu$.

Unfortunately, the picture [here](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/earth103/node/1018) shows that this Lipschitzness of $\log C(a)$ is a too optimistic assumption and one can only rely on the statement that the concentration was changing between some level and $1.5$ times that level (going down was not too sharp, but going up was rather dramatic each time). In that case the worst case scenarios are when $C(a)$ jumps from $1$ to $1.5$ at some point. This doesn't result in any closed form formula, but, just running the honest computation, we see that the error now is within $0.3$ units for $\lambda$ up to $0.3$ and stays at $0.15$ even when $\lambda$ approaches $0$, which by itself isn't that bad (any amount up to one standard deviation in the true age distribution, which is normalized to $1$ here shouldn't bother us too much and that will be attained only at $\lambda\approx 1.8$).

So, the key questions are

1. Is normality of the true age distribution a reasonable assumption?
2. What is the (estimated) standard deviation in the age distribution?
3. What is the half-life of ${}^{14}C$? (yeah, I can look that one up but you should know it by heart).

Once we know that, we can, probably, make some decent conclusions.

*Edit*: Let me just elaborate on what can be concluded about the error *without any assumption whatsoever*. As I said in the comments, you can then underestimate the true mean age by an arbitrarily large amount. However, assuming that the atmospheric carbon concentration $C$ was bounded between some level and $K$ times that level over the accumulation period, we can bound the possible overestimate. I will denote by $p$ the density of the deviation from the true mean, so $\int xp=0$ and normalize $\lambda$ to $1$ (so our unit of time is about 8267 years). Then we want to figure out how negative the quantity $\log\frac{\int Cpe^{x}}{\int Cp}$ be.

Note that if $C$ were constant, we would have the ratio of integrals at least $1$ by Jensen, so no overestimate would be possible at all. Now if we can find a probability distribution with $\int Cpe^x-u\int Cp=-v$ and $\int px=0$ for some positive $u<1$ and $v$, then we can satisfy the same equations by a linear combination of 2 Dirac measures, which will be non-degenerate because $v>0$, $u<1$ (we may lose the normalization $\int p=1$ but it doesn't matter). Thus, it is enough to find the minimum of the ratio
$$
\frac{Kbe^{-a}+ae^{b}}{Kb+a}, a,b>0\,.
$$
Using AM-GM, we see that it is at least
$$
K^{\frac b{a+b}}\frac{a+b}{Kb+a}\,.
$$
Normalizing to $a+b=1$ here, we get
$
K^b/[(K-1)b+1]
$
to minimize over $[0,1]$. This leads to the equation
$$
\log K[(K-1)b+1]-(K-1)=0\,,
$$
i.e.,
$$
b=\frac 1{\log K}-\frac 1{K-1}
$$
and finally to the logarithm of the minimum equal to
$$
\log\frac{\log K}{K-1}-\frac{\log K}{K-1}+1
$$
units of time.
For $K=1.5$, that is mere $-0.02$ units (about $170$ years). When $K=4$ (million years back in time), then it is $-0.234$ units (under $2000$ years). Even beyond that the belief is that $K\le 10$, which gives $-0.62$ units (about $5000$ years). Finally, even if we assume $K=100$ (quite an unbelievable atmosphere), then we still only get $-2.11$ units (under $18000$ years).

The moral is that an essential overestimate of the mean with the carbon method is pretty much impossible, so if you measured $X$ years, you can quite safely say that the ice is *at least* $X$ years old, but, unfortunately, this is where your knowledge ends. No upper bound is feasible without making assumptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I'm not sure if I understand everything that you say at once, but at least I can answer your questions:
1. Normality of the true age distribution is no assumption at all. As I have said: this distribution may be arbitrary (and cannot be guessed from first principles).
2. The standard deviation in the age distribution depends very much on the ice accumulation rate and on the specific processes taking place during firn-ice transition. In sum: it is also quite arbitrary.
3. Half-life of C14: 5,730 ± 40 years

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Then the answer is "the error can be quite arbitrary as well". Indeed, let's take $5730/\log 2=8267$ years as our time unit. Then $\lambda=1$. Let also $p$ be the density of the deviation from the mean age (so $\int px=0$). The error is then $\log\frac{\int Cp}{\int Cp e^{-x}}$. Since $e^{-x}$ is a nice convex function and $C$ is squeezed between $1$ and $1.5$, we can bound the error *from above* by about 170 years (assuming that you don't go too far back in time when the concentrations were much higher), but *no bound from below is possible* without further assumptions.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker In other words, you may be quite sure that you don't overestimate the true mean age but can underestimate it quite severely (which is intuitively obvious: if there is a noticeable portion (say $1/2$) of very ancient air bubbles together with $1/2$ of fairly recent ones, they will shift your estimate by the mere half-life, i.e. 5730 years, while the true mean age will skyrocket).

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I elaborated on my last comments showing the entire argument in the post. I don't know if you are happy with the conclusion, but that's what it is unless you want to make some "educated guesses" about the distribution :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Let me repeat my offer to send you a research paper which gives the complete background to my question - next to some interesting results, and quoting you. Just drop me a mail at stricker@syspedia.de.